# What are the rules for index names in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is limit length of index name? 
and what are characters that can use in index name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you try to create an index with a name whose length exceeds 255 characters (or ~100 UTF-8 encoded bytes) you'll get an error like this one

```
InvalidIndexNameException[Invalid index name [...], index name is too long, (266 > 255)]
```

As for the valid characters to use in an index, the best place to look for is in [their test suite](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/608a61ab85e82f8f6e88002ba7d8458411e7da62/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/MetaDataCreateIndexServiceTests.java#L188-L202), but basically an index name

- must not contain the characters `#`, `\`, `/`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `,`

  - Since ES 7.0 onwards, `:` is not allowed as well
- must not start with `_`, `-` or `+`
- must not be `.` or `..`
- must be lowercase

Comment: I think it should not contain `:` this as well.

Comment: Can it contain space?

Comment: is camelCase or snake_case supported ? or both?

Comment: @Typewar any casing is supported

Comment: @Typewar It cannot contain a space.

Answer (score 4):

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/indices-create-index.html

```
Lowercase only
Cannot include \, /, *, ?, ", <, >, |, ` ` (space character), ,, #
Indices prior to 7.0 could contain a colon (:), but that’s been deprecated and won’t be supported in 7.0+
Cannot start with -, _, +
Cannot be . or ..
Cannot be longer than 255 bytes (note it is bytes, so multi-byte characters will count towards the 255 limit faster)
```

Answer (score 2):

maximum length of index name is 255.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/8158/files